# Facebook quick replies API without text is sent back to the chat

Tags: python, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm using django python with [Facebook quick replies API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/quick-replies) to create a Facebook bot. And it works for me, but I want that everytime when user clicks on the "No" button, my bot will send nothing back to the chat.

Here is my code:

```
response_qr = json.dumps(
    {
        "recipient": {
            "id": fbid
        },
        "message": {
            "text": text,
            "quick_replies": [
                {
                    "content_type": "text",
                    "title": "Yes",
                    "payload": "YES"
                },
                {
                    "content_type": "text",
                    "title": "No",
                    "payload": "NO"
                }
            ]
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The "No" I get is from `"title": "No"`. So there is no way for me in this case to prevent Facebook sending the "No" text back. I can do it by replacing `"title": ""` but then it makes no sense because I want to ask user the Yes/No question. Not the Yes/(blank) or something else question.